# Function of type ('a -> 'b) list -> 'a -> 'b list in OCaml

Tags: list, types, polymorphism, ocaml

> Write any Ocaml function whose type is `('a -> 'b) list -> 'a -> 'b list`

`('a -> 'b) list` is the part that confuses me the most. I'm new to OCaml and having a hard time understanding how to write a function to get a specific datatype type.

```
# let int x = x+1;;
# let fcn = [int; int];;
```

So I'm passing a function a function and a variable. I'm going to take that variable an add it to each element of the list and return the list?

Answer (score 6):

`('a -> 'b)` means a function which goes from type `'a` to type `'b`. Basically you need to make a function which takes a list of functions that take `'a` and return `'b`, plus a specific `'a` value, and which returns a list of `'b` values (probably by applying each function of the list of functions to the specific `'a` value).

Answer (score 3):

As this is homework, I will not provide you with a complete solution. But, as a hint, I would suggest that you take a look at this implementation of the familiar `map` function:

```
let rec map f = function
  | [] -> []
  | x :: xs -> f x :: map f xs
```

It has type `('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list` which means that it takes as its first argument a function that takes values of some type `'a` to values of some type `'b`, as its second argument a list of elements of type `'a`, and that it produces a list of elements of type `'b`. It proceeds by pattern matching on the argument list and, recursively applying the function (`f`) to every element `x` of the list.

Now have a look at the type of the function that you have to write? What does it tell you about the required behaviour of that function? Keeping the implementation of the `map` function in mind, how would you write your function?

Answer (score 1):

```
('a -> 'b) list -> 'a -> 'b list
```

This means that your function has two parameters

- A list of `('a -> 'b)` which represents a function taking an element of type `'a` as a parameter and returning an element of type `'b`. As you can see, these types are abstract, so they could be of any types for instance `(int -> int)` or `(int -> float)` etc...
- An elements of types `'a`. Notice that this type must be the same as the parameter of your function.

So you'll build the resulting list with the element you give as a parameter.

Here is a little example:

```
let action l a =
  let rec todo l res =
    match l with
      | [] -> res
      | h :: t -> todo t res@[h a] in
  todo l []
```

so here, any function of type `int -> int` will be accepted. The same thing goes for any other type as long as you don't mix them with other types.

Answer (score 0):

```
let rec func f a = match f with          (* ( 'a->'b ) list -> 'a -> 'b list *)
                       |[]->[]
                       |x::lr -> x a :: func lr a;;
```

that may help ! it works fine 
 
***1 -*** So as we know , ocaml create the type of our function line by line

***2 -*** in this function we have two arguments **f** and **a**

***3 -*** **( 'a->'b ) list**  :   for **f**

***4 -*** **'a** : for **a** 
  ***! how ocaml did that ?*** listen !

***5 -*** when we matched f with [ ] 'blank list' ocaml release that is a list **(****)list** but doesn't know what contains yet in the last line of the code he will do ok ? nice ! 
 
-  here we are in the last line of the code and we have only f of type list  -

***6 -*** **x :: lr** means we sort the first element of the element that is matched before : **f** and we add **a** here ocaml gives a type for **a** and for the list elements which is matched : **f** as first elements ocaml gives them types from **'a** to **'z** so here we have **('a->'b) list** for **f** and **'a** for **a** 
-here we have **f** of type : **('a->'b) list**  , and   **a** of type :  **'a**

***7 -*** the result of this function **'b list** so it's up to you to answer in comment ! **:D thank you**